# Is it possible to setthe page to use the same viewmodel as one of its elements in code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm trying to create a page in my Windows Phone app using the MVVM Light Framework that will dynamically load one of several UserControls as its primary UI element. The UserControl is loaded and inserted in the page's code-behind file.

```
public partial class HomePage
{
    private readonly UserControl _caseBrowser;

    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _caseBrowser = new StandardCaseBrowserControl { IsEnabled = true };
        DataContext = ((FBViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"]).StandardCasesViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoaded(sender, e);

        // add a case browser to the content panel
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(_caseBrowser);

        // more stuff that is beyond the scope of this question
    }
}
```

Each of the UserControls are also bound to their own ViewModels in the xaml. I am trying to have the page itself bind to the same ViewModel as the UserControl being loaded.

I tried simply assigning the DataContext:

```
        _caseBrowser = new StandardCaseBrowserControl { IsEnabled = true }; // the usercontrol
        DataContext = _caseBrowser.DataContext;
```

but that came up null.

I also tried binding to the static ViewModel as supplied by the ViewModelLocator:

```
        _caseBrowser = new StandardCaseBrowserControl { IsEnabled = true };
        DataContext = FBViewModelLocator.StandardCasesViewModelStatic;
```

but that creates a new instance of the viewmodel, so that the page and the usercontrol are working on two separate instances of the viewmodel.

I also tried using the instance of the viewmodelocator in the Application Resources:

```
        _caseBrowser = new StandardCaseBrowserControl { IsEnabled = true };
        DataContext = ((FBViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"]).StandardCasesViewModel;
```

and the same thing happened.

Does anyone know if there's a good way to do this, or if I should just scrap this and find a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the DataContext of the _caseBrowser isn't set when you try to assign it to the page's DataContext. I'd suggest signing up for the _caseBrowser's DataContextChanged event and assigning the page's DataContext when the _caseBrowser's DataContext changes. Something like:

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _caseBrowser = new StandardCaseBrowserControl { IsEnabled = true };
    _caseBrowser.DataContextChanged += _OnCaseBrowsesrDataContextChanged;
}


private void OnCaseBrowserDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_caseBrowser.DataContext != null)
        DataContext = _caseBrowser.DataContext;
}
```

Comment: It appears there is no DataContextChanged event on the UserControl. Is it something I would have to create myself?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like Windows Phone doesn't supports DataContextChanged. If you want to still use this approach then I would recommend adding a property to your UserControl that sets the DataContext and raises an event to notify the page that DataContext of the _caseBrowser has been set.

Comment: I will probably have to do that. Thanks.